# what is the correct way to save chatgpt api-key for flutter app/firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, openai-api

I have made some research, some said I have to hardcoded but using obfuscation in my client app, I see this may be a easy way. But I am not sure for the following reason:

1. Since I need to check how many tokens one user is using, anyway I need firebase as my backend/server to give the permission to the specific user, in this case saving chatgpt apikey in firebase is better?
2. The other solution like a. --dart-define; b.ENVied/.env seems not hundred percent safe, so I do not have such experience how to save such as chatgpt api level, should I follow this solution?

So do we have some official solution or any existing tutorial how to handle the connection between chatgpt api and flutter app?

==============**Update**===============

Hi Alex I have read your medium article and have following questions:

1. Is it safe to use firebase extension where I input my openai api-key? I am confused where to save this openai api-key in the end: Google Cloud Console/Secret manager or Chatbot with ChatGPT Firebase Extension?
2. I know flutter instead of android, from my understanding in your [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-create-a-chatbot-with-firebase-firestore-and-chatgpt-on-android-910dd40f11d9), it seems a user can directly connect with firebase and chatgpt since I input my openai apikey in the Chatbot with ChatGPT Firebase Extension, so how can we control how many tokens this user is allowed to use?
3. Do you have also some article introducing the third-party-payment api such as stripes or revenueCat, so firebase knows the specific user is a premium user and give more chatgpt quota?

Thanks!

Comment: Aside from my answer, if you're looking for a solution for Android, then I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-create-a-chatbot-with-firebase-firestore-and-chatgpt-on-android-910dd40f11d9) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreChatGPT).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want to save the OpenAI API Key on the client, which I recommend against it, you can indeed do it by obfuscating it, but the safest place would be to store it in Google Cloud. So you should open your [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/), select your project, then go to the Secret Manager at:

- https://console.cloud.google.com/security/secret-manager?project=your-project

And create your secret key. The benefit of using this approach is that the encryption is managed by Google. So you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for your detailed and informative answer, now I am just learning your medium article, this is a new world for me and your answer helps me a lot!

Comment: Hi Alex, I update my question, plz check it, thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey Matti. If you have any other question that derives from this one, then it's considered a new question and should be added separately. So please post a new question, here on StackOverflow, and explain what you have tried and what exactly doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: hi alex, thanks for the info, I raise another question, plz check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76710350/how-to-connect-secret-manager-and-firebase

Comment: Sure. I'll take a look and if I'll know the answer, I'll write to you.

Comment: But don't you use a secret to access Secret Manager?  So where is that secret kept?  It's just turtles all the way down isn't it?